# PHP a Text as a URL / LINK

Tags: php

I have a question, i have a .php file with this:

```
$url = "http://domain.com/folder/sub/file.jpg"
```

A mail will be send like this :

```
$message = 'MP3 file called "'. $name .'" can be downloaded at the following link: '. $url;
```

But now if the mail is been sent you will see the whole URL in the mail like this: MP3 File called: Name here, can be downloaded at the following link: http://domain.com/folder/sub/file.jpg

But can i also make it like this: [Download Now](http://#) with the `$url` string as the link? So yes how can i do that the simplest way?

So the mail will show like this:
MP3 File called : Name here , can be downloaded here: [DOWNLOAD](http://#)

Comment: Can't you use the `<a></a>` ?

Comment: `$headers` != `$header` where does that code come from, I've seen this a few times now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed regular html / href tags inside the email message once the header depicts that the message has `html` code:

```
$header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n";
```

In your case, the email message would look like:

```
  $message = 'MP3 file called "'. $name .'" can be downloaded at the following link: <a href="'.$url.'"> Download Now</a>';
```

Comment: I editted my answer, copy the `$message` code again.

Comment: @Dombre You have the wrong variable names. See comment on question.

Comment: @Dombre you overwrite the variable on the second assignment, use `.=` there.